# Laravel Multiple relationship with eloquent model

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have 3 tables, Product, Images and Color table.

images table belongs to product table and also belongs to color table.
Inside product controller I need get data related to product like: product images and images color from color table.

Product model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Image;
use App\Color;
class Product extends Model {
public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

}

Product Controller:

```
$products = Product::with('images', 'images.colors')->get();
```

Images model:

```
use App\Product;
use App\Color;
class Image extends Model {
public function products() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
public function colors() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Color::class);
}
```

Color Model:

```
public function colorTags() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image', 'color_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: what do you need the output to be?

Comment: I'm assuming you've read about [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) Eloquent relationships in the docs?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is answered here:
[Laravel get related models of related models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553196/laravel-get-related-models-of-related-models)

In your case:
return Product::find($id)->images->colors->load('colorTags');

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue.

It looks like the issue might be the fact that you're using "colors" as the method name for the relation.

Try changing:

```
public function colors() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Color::class);
}
```

to

```
public function colours() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Color::class);
}
```

And I think it will work.

I've also had this issue using the words "assets", and "templates" as relation names. It appears that there are some certain keywords which will conflict with something else that eloquent is doing. It would be good if we could get a list of these form somewhere.